# Autocad API , reading block attributes casting error

Tags: vb.net, autocad-plugin

I am receiving following error that

> "Unable to cast object of type
>   autodesk.autocad.databaseservices.polyline to type 
>   autodesk.autocad.databaseservices.blockrefereance

while reading block attributes with lot of stuff on drawing.

Code:

```
Dim db As Database = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database

Using tr As Transaction = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction

Dim ed As Editor = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor
Dim blockids As ObjectIdCollection = New ObjectIdCollection
Dim bt As BlockTable = tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead)
Dim btr As BlockTableRecord = tr.GetObject(bt(BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace), OpenMode.ForRead)

For Each objid As ObjectId In btr

    If btr.IsAnonymous = False Or btr.IsLayout = False Then

        Dim blkref As BlockReference = tr.GetObject(objid, OpenMode.ForRead)

        Dim attcol As AttributeCollection = blkref.AttributeCollection

        For Each attid As ObjectId In attcol

            Dim attref As AttributeReference = tr.GetObject(attid, OpenMode.ForRead)

            ed.WriteMessage(attref.Tag.ToString & vbNewLine)

            ed.WriteMessage(attref.TextString.ToString & vbNewLine)

        Next

    End If

Next

tr.Commit()

End Using
```

Can you please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is the problem?**

I have a shopping basket full of all sorts of goods/products. Milk, baking soda, apples. Bananas. Some things are edible, some are very poisonous. If I assume that all things are edible and I try to eat some things - that could cause some very serious problems. e.g. I can eat apples, but if i try to eat a toothbrush then my body will crash and throw an error. I must first check that it is edible before putting it in my mouth.........ah, ok let's move on.....It is the same with Autocad.

The solution is simple: First check if the object you are dealing with is a blockReference. If it is so, then continue. I haven't checked the below code, because i'm not a VB.NET expert, but something like this will allow you to check if you're dealing with a blockReference before continuing:

```
For Each objid As ObjectId In btr

If btr.IsAnonymous = False Or btr.IsLayout = False Then

  Dim ent as Entity = tr.GetObject(objid, OpenMode.ForRead)  // ADD THIS LINE

  If TypeOf ent Is [BlockReference] Then            // ADD THIS IF STATEMENT


             // ADD IN THE REST OF YOUR CODE HERE 
             // e.g.  Dim blkref As BlockReference = tr.GetObject(objid, 
             //  OpenMode.ForRead) etc.



  End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looping through the btr (ModelSpace) but it's assuming it's dealing with blocks only.

You need  another check before to confirm what type of entity you're inspecting.  Preferably before you check if it's anonymous.